# Time data errors in input while trying to get the sum from txt.file (PYTHON)

Tags: python, csv, datetime, error-handling, text-files

the program i am trying to make is supposed to get a user to input a start date and end date and the program is to iterate through the list which is in a txt file containing such info as

```
1-2-2014,store1,42305.67,23
12-4-2014,store2,21922.22,17
10-2-2015,store3,63277.9,32
10-5-2015,store4,83290.09,16
```

the information is separated by commas. the third number figures are values representing money. for example if a user enters (referring to above txt file info example)

```
start date as 1-2-2014
end date as 10-2-2015
```

the program is meant to calculate the figures representing money from start date including figures from in between dates if there are any ( above example dates i have entered shows there is one date in between ) and print the total sum.

the program is supposed to work with any start and end date input that is in the txt file and print no such record exists if there is no record.

below are two different programs with help from others that are supposed to do that that i have come up with but produce errors which i am hoping someone can fix and point out where i went wrong.

code one with error stated at the end:

```
from datetime import datetime

def calculate(file_name, s_date, e_date):
dollar = 0
_format = '%d-%m-%Y'
start_date = datetime.strptime(s_date, _format)
end_date = datetime.strptime(e_date, _format)
with open(file_name) as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        l = line.split(',')
        date = datetime.strptime(l[0], _format)
        if date >= start_date and date <= end_date:
            dollar = dollar + float(l[2])
return dollar

start_date = raw_input('Enter start date')
end_date = raw_input('Enter end date')
result = calculate('file.dat', start_date, end_date)
print (result) 


ValueError: time data '\n' does not match format '%d-%m-%Y'
```

FYI (date input was input as 1-2-2014 and 10-2-2015)

code 2 below with error stated at the end:

```
from datetime import datetime

begin_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter start date (dd mm yyyy): '), '%d %m %Y')
end_date = datetime.strptime(input('Enter end date (dd mm yyyy): '), '%d %m %Y')

with open ('data.txt', 'r') as f:
total = 0
for line in f:
    strlist = line.rstrip().split(',')

    dt = datetime.strptime(strlist[0], '%d %m %Y')

    if begin_date <= dt <= end_date:
        total+=float(strlist[2].split('$')[1])




print(total)




ValueError: time data '' does not match format '%d %m %Y'
```

thanks. green tick for solution

Answer (score 0):

Problem in date formats:

```
%m  Month as a zero-padded decimal number.
%d  Day of the month as a zero-padded decimal number.
```

You are using this formats but they have to contain 2 digits.

Like 01,03,10 and so on.

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)